# Unable to remove object from list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a method that iterates through a list of objects and if it finds one that matches a certain criterion, it is supposed to delete it:

```
public static void MakeChanges(MappingFileModel modelWithChanges)
{
    foreach (var mapping in Mapping)
    {
        if (mapping.ScanIndex.Equals(modelWithChanges.ScanIndex))
        {
            if (modelWithChanges.Column == -1)
            {
                Mapping.Remove(mapping);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fairly simple, I would have thought: The method takes an instance of a `MappingFileModel` called `modelWithChanges`, then iterates over the list, finds the instance where the `ScanIndex` strings match. It then checks if the `Column == -1`, (I've deleted the `else` statements for other options for brevity). So, if those two `if` statements evaluate to `true`, I want to remove `mapping` from the list `Mapping`.

Problem is, it doesn't remove it. I doesn't throw an error, either. It just doesn't do it. It does hit the statement if I set a breakpoint. I have also tried:

```
Mapping.RemoveAt(Mapping.IndexOf(mapping));
```

That does through an Index out of range error, which would indicate that my code can't locate `mapping` in `Mapping`. That makes no sense, since I am iterating over `Mapping`?

**Update:**

Thanks to pointing out the other article... I edited my code to the following:

```
public static void MakeChanges(MappingFileModel modelWithChanges)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i<Mapping.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Mapping[i].ScanIndex.Equals(modelWithChanges.ScanIndex))
            {
                if (modelWithChanges.Column == -1)
                {
                    Mapping.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It still doesn't remove that object...

**Update 2:**

Ok, so I have now gone one step further and created a variable outside the loop... and it still doesn't delete the object. It's there. There is no error.

```
public static void MakeChanges(MappingFileModel modelWithChanges)
    {
        var deleteIndex = -1;

        for (var i =0; i<Mapping.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Mapping[i].ScanIndex.Equals(modelWithChanges.ScanIndex))
            {
                if (modelWithChanges.Column == -1)
                {
                    deleteIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }

        if (deleteIndex != -1)
        {
            Mapping.RemoveAt(deleteIndex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make changes to a collection while iterating over it using `foreach`. If you want to update it, then try using `for` loop.

For more details, refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a90c87be-9553-4d48-9892-d482ee325f02/why-cant-change-value-in-foreach?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: Thank you (facepalm). I forgot about that!

Comment: Thanks to overeager diiN_______, and HimBromBeere, who instead of looking at the problem, just stamped it as duplicate... I found the bug, and it had nothing to do with the code I presented. 
For those who are looking for a solution to this, if they come across this: The problem was with the list itself. It was a static property of a class and the getter kept refreshing the contents of the list whenever it was requested. It didn't matter how often I changed the list, the getter always refreshed it again.